# Using httpclientBuilder in Apache Camel 2.21.5 Olingo4 component

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm, olingo

Spring Boot 1.5.14 app using apache camel 2.21.5 and camel-olingo4 component. It seems to default to using the httpAsyncClientBuilder even though I explicitly set the httpClientBuilder in the configuration.

Setting the httpClientBuilder in the Olingo4Configuration explicitly in configuration class, but olingo4 component still wants to use the async httpclient.

looking closer at the Olingo4Component class.. seems the code ignores any configured httpClientBuilder and forces use of http async client builder.

```
private Olingo4AppWrapper createOlingo4App(Olingo4Configuration configuration) {

    Object clientBuilder = configuration.getHttpAsyncClientBuilder();
    if (clientBuilder == null) {
        HttpAsyncClientBuilder asyncClientBuilder = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create();
```

In my spring config class, i setup the Olingo configuration as bean:

```
@Bean
public Olingo4Configuration olingo4Configuration(HttpClientConfigurationProperties httpClientConfigProps,
        MSDynamicsConfigurationProperties dynamicsConfigProps) {

    Olingo4Configuration config = new Olingo4Configuration();
        config.setHttpClientBuilder(httpClientBuilder(httpClientConfigProps, dynamicsConfigProps));
    config.setServiceUri(dynamicsConfigProps.getServiceRoot());

    return config;
}
```

I'm expecting Olingo comp. to use the http client builder i define above, but the http wire debug is showing it's using the aysnc client instead.

http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1.3 (Java/1.8.0_191)

Thoughts?

Comment: Make sure the component uses your custom Olingo4Configuration, eg make sure to use the -starter JARs from Camel also. And even if you have that bean, then the configuration class may not be auto discovered, it's component specific if they can do that. So you may need to configure the camel component to use this config configuration class fx via application.properties you another @Bean where you can create the camel component and inject the configuration class, and set it via the java code

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen.... only way i can get this to work is to set the httpAsyncClientBuilder in the config... setting the HttpClientBuilder in my config gets overriden by the above code in the Olingo4Component.createOlingo4App. If the asyncBuilder is null, it goes ahead and instantiates one to use... so my httpClientBuilder is never used. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe you can try to fix this and provide a PR then its easier to look at and review